# Modify crawled URL before indexing it

Tags: apache, solr, lucene, nutch

I am using nutch 1.4. I want to manipulate the crawled url before indexing it.

For example, if my URL is http://xyz.com/home/xyz.aspx then I want to modify the URL to http://xyz.com/index.aspx?role=xyz and only the latter field should be indexed in SOLR. The reason is I don't want to expose the first URL. The 2nd URL will ultimately redirect it to same page.

Do we have a provision in Nutch to manipulate the crawled URL's before indexing it to SOLR??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box way to modify the value fed to solr unless you write a custom plugin to do so.
However, this can be easily handled at client side before the results are displayed to the User.